# Xcode [ESC] fail to auto complete the property in .m file

Tags: iphone, xcode, properties, autocomplete

I have declared a property in the header file, for example

```
@interface myClass {
    NSArray* data;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* data;
```

when I want to synthesize it in the .m file, I press 'ESC' and expect the property 'data' will appear in the list but it doesn't ?

```
@implementation
@synthesize da[ESC]
```

It prompts 'No completions found'

any help? many thanks ~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sometimes takes a little while for Xcode to update its autocomplete database. Unlike the Visual Studio IDE, it's not done instantly with any code change.

Comment: Can I manually adjust the interval Xcode update its autocomplete database? Thanks