# How to make Xcode autocomplete @property

Tags: xcode, autocomplete

How can I make Xcode autocomplete a `@property` directive?
I saw it on someone's Mac.

Comment: Are you certain yoi did not see the @synthesize property being auto-completed ?

Comment: @Jean No, I specifically saw @ property ( , ) type *name (or something like that).

Comment: Smells like third-party-utility text expansion (something like what [Dash](http://kapeli.com/) does for example)... Or a custom snippet in Xcode

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Alladinian already mentioned in a comment, you can achieve this with a custom "Code Snippet" in Xcode. To define a code snippet, you first type the text in a source file,
for example

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) <#type#> *<#name#>;
```

(`<#...#>` is a special placeholder, so that you can jump to "type" and "name" using the
tabulator key later.)

Then you select the entire line, and drag it to the "Code Snippet Library":

[image]

Double-click on the new code snippet, and give it a name and a shortcut:

[image]

Now, when you type the shortcut, Xcode will offer the completion:

[image]

Select your code snippet, and it will be inserted in the source file:

[image]

You can use the tabulator to jump to "type" and "name".

Comment: To those coming to this unable to drag the text selection, you need to click and hold for a second or two before you are able to drag. Otherwise, you are just changing your text selection region.

Comment: for new folks (me): 'Completion Shortcut' is a key line for xcode to recognize your shortcut.  e.g., in above example, if 'Completion Shortcut' were 'tt', then i type 'tt' in xcode, can press enter to select '@property (nonatomic, strong) <#type#> *<#name#>;' (thank you Martin R for great, clear answer)

Answer (score 2):

Check the box shown in RedBox, your XCode autocompletion will work

[image]

EDIT:

If you are able to see in .m file, then surely your .h contains some syntax error. Due to that error LLVM compiler shows signal to correct and your autocompletion is not working.

EDIT 2:

As per your comment, while typing `@prop` the autocompletion does not show `erty(,)` even in XCode4.6

[image]

Comment: Apparently, Shimi Bitton has already done it since he has "no problem with @synthesize autocompletion".

Comment: @Jean: check my edit. If these are not the case then this question may be fake.

Comment: The question may be fake. Unless he is talking about the "readwrite" "strong" etc. auto-completion not working. An heavy syntax error could indeed prevent auto-completion from working properly.

Comment: I really don't understand why do you think this is fake?   Xcode autocompletion works fine for me in both the .h and .m files.  I just saw a completion of a property which I didn't know was possible, so I asked how can I enable it..

Comment: @ShimiBitton: What type of completion you see? when you write `@prop` remaining text `erty` comes automatically or what?

Comment: Then it must not be XCode!!! I am using XCode4.6 and you can see the screen shot in answer. Was he using some other IDE like AppCode?

Comment: No, it was definitely Xcode. I guess it's a plugin like @Alladinian said.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I know, that's why I asked. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The @property does not auto-complete itself. However, the @synthesize does.
See this question:

[Xcode [ESC] fail to auto complete the property in .m file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577628/xcode-esc-fail-to-auto-complete-the-property-in-m-file)

Comment: I have no problem with @synthesize autocompletion. I specifically saw: @ property (     ,     ) type *name (or something like that).

Comment: How could Xcode guess the name of the new property you are declaring ?

Comment: It didn't, i just can't remember what EXACTLY was in that part, hence the "or something like that"...

Comment: So, you mean that in @property(readwrite, retain) NSString* myStr; you  expect auto-completion to provide the readwrite and the retain ? Or is it something else ?

Comment: No, I expect it to autocomplete the way it autocompletes a method, where you have to fill the rest using TAB (like CGRectMake for example).